# Alpine.js: How to make ref element visible and focus on click?

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

When I press on the link "Hallo", I want that the link "Okay" is visible and focused. However, when I click on "Hallo", the "Okay" link will become visible, but its not focused. Only if I click again the link "Okay" will be focused. How can I achieve it with to show and focus the link with one click?

```css
  a:focus{
      color:yellow;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.js"></script>
<div x-data="{open:false}">
  <a href="#" @click="open=true;$refs.foo.focus()" >Hallo</a>
  <div x-show="open">
    <a href="#" x-ref="foo">Okay</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your JS is executed, the `foo` element is not shown yet, so it cannot be focused. You need to wait for it to be shown before focusing it. [`$nextTick`](https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine#nexttick) allows you to do just that:

> `$nextTick` is a magic property that allows you to only execute a given expression AFTER Alpine has made its reactive DOM updates. **This is useful for times you want to interact with the DOM state AFTER it's reflected any data updates you've made.**

```css
a:focus{
  color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.js"></script>
<div x-data="{open:false}">
  <a href="#" @click="open=true;$nextTick(() => { $refs.foo.focus(); });" >Hallo</a>
  <div x-show="open">
    <a href="#" x-ref="foo">Okay</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Is it possible to pass $nextTick to a function and call it there? Or can I only call it inline?

You can add a `myMethod` property to `x-data`, and access everything through `this`:

```js
const appData = {
  open: false,
  myMethod() {
    this.open = true;
    this.$nextTick(() => { this.$refs.foo.focus(); });
  }
};
```

```css
a:focus {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.js"></script>
<div x-data="appData">
  <a href="#" @click="myMethod">Hallo</a>
  <div x-show="open">
    <a href="#" x-ref="foo">Okay</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass `$nextTick` to a function and call it there? Or can I only call it inline? I tried something like `@click="myMethod($nextTick)" and `myMethod($nextTick) { this.open=true; $nextTick(() => { $refs.foo.focus(); });}`  but that didnt work

Comment: Sure, but you'll need to make a couple of other adjustments. I edited the answer

Comment: oh nice! I hought that would not work, because I tried it before with `this.$event`. Thanks!